# Не работает DataBindings. Точнее не могу правильно воспользоватся

Tags: c#, winforms

Проблема вот в чем:
Мне нужно сделать так, что бы при присвоении некой ссылке (например Source1) нового объекта, его содержимое мгновенно отображались на форме в заданных полях.
К примеру вот:

```
tb_TextBox0.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", Source1, "Name"));
tb_TextBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", Source1, "Nominal"));
pb_PictureBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Image", Source1, "Flag"));
lbl_Label.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", Source1, "CharCode"));
```

Я связал  некие Controls (TextBox, PictureBox, Label) с неким источником данных (Source1).
При присвоении ему (Source1) нового объекта ничего не происходит.

```
Source1 = new MyClass("Vasya", /*argument*/);
```

Контролы показывают старую информацию.
Никакие ControlUpdateMode и DataSourceUpdateMode не помогают.
На форумах нашел информацию о BindingContext но так ничего и не понял.
Прошу подсказать, что сделать для нормальной привязки.

Comment: Нужно реализовать интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged` у вашего источника - `MyClass`.

Answer (score 0):

Действительно. Для решения данной проблемы достаточно реализовать интерфейс

```
INotifyPropertyChanged
```

у источника ваших данных.